# Get any site data in .txt file using curl in php?

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to get the data of any website in my .txt file using curl in php.
so there is some issue in code. yesterday i get the data in web_content.txt file. But i don not know why and where error generate i am not getting the site url in .txt file.
Here is my code you can check and please help me what should i do to remove this error and get the data.

```html
<?php
   if($_REQUEST['url_text'] == "") {
    echo "<div class='main_div border_radius'><div class='sub_div'> Please type any site URL.</div></div>";
   } else {
    $site_url = $_REQUEST['url_text'];
    $curl_ref=curl_init();//init the curl
    curl_setopt($curl_ref,CURLOPT_URL,$site_url);// Getting site 
    curl_setopt($curl_ref,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,2);
    curl_setopt($curl_ref,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    $site_data = curl_exec($curl_ref);
    if (empty($site_data)) {
      echo "<div class='main_div border_radius'><div class='sub_div'> Data is not available.</div></div>";
    }
    else {
      echo "<div class='main_div border_radius'><div class='sub_div'>".$site_data."</div></div>";
    }
    $fp = fopen("web_content.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");//Open a file in write mode
    curl_setopt($curl_ref, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($curl_ref, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_exec($curl_ref);
    curl_close($curl_ref);
    fclose($fp);
   }
  ?>
```

```html
if(isset($_GET['start_tag_textbox']) && ($_GET['end_tag_textbox'])) {
     get_tag_data($_GET['start_tag_textbox'],$_GET['end_tag_textbox']);
   }
   header('content-type: text/plain');
   function get_tag_data ($start,$end) {
    $file_data= "";
    $tag_data = "";
    $file = fopen("web_content.txt","r");
    $file_data = fread($file,filesize("web_content.txt"));
    fclose($file);
    $last_pos = strpos($start,'>');
    $start = substr_replace($start,".*>",$last_pos);
    
    preg_match_all('#'.$start.'(.*)'.$end.'#U',$file_data,$matches);
    for($i=0; $i<count($matches[1]);$i++){
     echo $matches[1][$i]."\n";
    }
    
    
   }
   
  ?>
```

```html
<?php
   $url = "http://www.ucertify.com";  
   $ch = curl_init();   
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);  
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  

   $output = curl_exec($ch);  
   curl_close($ch);  

   $file = fopen("web_content.txt","w");
   fwrite($file,$output);
   fclose($file);
  ?>
```

Comment: "what should i do to remove this error" You could start by telling us what the error is.

Comment: actually i am not getting error. when in my web_content.txt. i am not getting the data of website so here is above my code please review. thank you

Comment: Please don't use unrelated tags, as it stands this question has nothing to do with CakePHP. If it's somehow related, then please elaborate on that - thanks!